# Good way to send result of 'uname -a' to a stream?

Tags: c++, stream, exec, uname

What is a good way to call 'uname -a' from a C++ program and send the results to a stream?

I looked at system() and exec(), but they do not seem to give access to the stdout of the call.

Thanks.

-William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just retrieve the strings *directly* from the [struct utsname](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/utsname.h.html) returned from the [uname(2)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/uname.html) system call found on most Unix/Unix-like platforms?

No need to fork a "**uname -a**" process.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if you are using Qt) is to use QProcess.